# Running MATLAB installed on a cluster from mac

Tags: linux, macos, matlab

I recently switched to mac from ubuntu, and I was wondering if there is any way in which I can use the MATLAB installed in a Linux cluster in my mac.

I can run it without user interface, by using `ssh` and `nojvm` (i.e. `matlab -nojvm`, where `jvm` stands for java virtual machine). I was wondering if it was possible for me to run it with the user interface. When I try to launch MATLAB normally, I get the error `Warning: No window system found.  Java option 'Desktop' ignored.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is perfectly possible, but did not work initially because `X11` was not installed. Apparently it is not included in Yosemite. Installing it solved the problem.